# Display Time in input control type of time

Tags: c#, html

In C#, I have a DateTime field where I only want to display the Time in an input control of type 'time'.

Field Sample:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartTime" runat="server" MaxLength="10" CssClass="form-control" type="time"></asp:TextBox>
```

Neither of these will work:

```
txtStartTime.Text = ((System.DateTime)pDS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["StartTime"]).ToShortTimeString(); 

System.String strResult = System.String.Format("{0:hh:mm tt}", pDS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["StartTime"].ToString());
txtStartTime.Text = strResult;
```

Comment: Remove the ToString in the string.Format line and it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object_) needs an object to apply the format. The documentation tells us that the method:

> Replaces one or more format items in a string with the string representation of a specified object.

The string representation of the `string` is the `string` itself. So your format string has no effect on the string that you pass to it. 
But it can format a `Datetime` object, since the format you use has a valid string representation match.

So simply remove the ToString call and your approach will work.

```
System.String strResult = System.String.Format("{0:hh:mm tt}", pDS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["StartTime"]);
txtStartTime.Text = strResult;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ToString(format)` method of the `DateTime` class itself:

```
DateTime dt = ((System.DateTime)pDS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["StartTime"]);
txtStartTime.Text = dt.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Datetime.ToString(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_)
To get hour format just use `ToString("hh:mm:ss")`

Example:

```
 <%

        var dt = DateTime.Now;//((System.DateTime)pDS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["StartTime"]);
        txtStartTime.Text = dt.ToString("hh:mm:ss");

    %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartTime" runat="server" MaxLength="10" CssClass="form-control" type="time"></asp:TextBox>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```